# Геттеры-сеттеры в Java

Tags: java

Я новичок в программировании, и очень прошу помочь мне разобраться с геттерами и сеттерами. Как работать с ними - я примерно поняла. Мне не понятно, как они относятся к инкапсуляции? Судя по гуглу, это настолько просто, что инфы толковой просто нет...

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Этот вопрос для меня прояснился!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

В Java данные отделены от методов, дабы предотвратить неверную модификацию этих самых данных, т.е. по сути реализована основа для инкапсуляции. Соответственно для доступа (или правильного доступа) к данным Вам необходимо иметь соответствующие функции. Роль эту и играют функции-геттеры и функции-сеттеры, реализующие, кроме всего прочего, прозрачный интерфейс для работы с данными.

В реализации данных методов и заключен принцип инкапсуляции. По сути вы не видите, как данные обрабатываются (вам известен лишь интерфейс, через который, и только через который вы можете взаимодействовать с объектом), а значит можете быть уверены, в корректности обработки данных, чего нельзя сказать при работе с данными напрямую. Естественно кроме корректности вы получаете целостность, относительную простоту и т.д.

С точки зрения программиста, реализующего данный интерфейс так же необходимо помнить о том, что ваши классы и/или интерфейсы, возможно, будет кто-то использовать, а значит есть необходимость реализовывать геттеры и сеттеры, а не давать на растерзание данные.

Простейший пример: вам необходимо хранить таблицу, которая имеет n-строк, m-столбцов. Для конечного пользователя по сути не должно быть важно, какая структура данных хранит эту таблицу внутри вашего класса, при использовании функции получения k-той строки (пусть это будет хоть массив, хоть список, хоть целая база данных).

Небольшой код для данного примера:

```
class SuperTableNM {
 private ArrayList<Hashtable<String>> ourTable;
 //constructors and ...
 public Hashtable<String> getLine(int lineNumber) {
  //ваша реализация...
 }
}
```

И еще из наболевшего, например, вы хотите хранить IP-адрес, создавать класс вы можете используя десятичную нотацию IP-адресов в виде обычных строк. Но хранить так адреса не экономично, можно использовать числа 4-байтовые целые или массив из четырех байт. Но получаете вы и выдаете IP только в виде строк. А значит:

```
class IPAddress {
 private short a;
 private short b;
 private short c;
 private short d;

 public IPAddress(String ip) {
  //используем сеттер
  this.setIP(ip);
 }
 private void setIP(String ip) {
  //проверки корректности
  //разбиение на байты... т.п.
 }
 public String getIP() {
  //склеивание наших байт в строку
 }
}
```

Comment: все действительно безумно просто, примеров инкапсуляции данных полно повсюду:   
чтоб проверить уровень бензина или скорость автомобиля достаточно глянуть на панель приборов. датчики на панели и есть интерфейс. вас интересуют цифры вам не интересно состояние поплавка внутри бака, или количество оборотов сделаных колесами, и то каким образом эти значения преобразуются в нужные вам цыфры