# Геттеры, сеттеры и инкапсуляция

Tags: java, setter, getter

Окей. С самого первого знакомства с инкапсуляцией и её свойствами сокрытия данных, для меня остается непонятным один момент: поля класса, помеченные модификатором `private`, недоступны другим классам - это ясно. 
Допустим:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public class Cat {
        private String name;

        public Cat(String name) {
            this.name = name;

        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) { // этот метод противоречит принципам инкапсуляции

            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Когда мы вызываем метод `setName("Васька")`, ведь он меняет значение поля? Если да, то это мне не очень понятно. Я имею в виду: какая разница, отметили ли мы поле модификатором доступа `private`? Если мы получаем доступ к нему через сеттер и меняем его значение как хотим?

Comment: это дает больше  контроля над кодом. ведь на сеттер можно повесить проверку на валидность данных, какой-нибудь калбэк или залочить мутексом

Comment: в хорошо спроектированном классе практически нет геттеров и сеттеров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуй, заново расписывать велосипед не стану, ибо вопросов, аналогичных вашему, в интернете предостаточно - вот, например: [Геттеры-сеттеры в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34713/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-java), или ещё вот: [Java. Зачем геттеры и сеттеры для полей public? (кроме проверок)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586582/java-%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-public-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA?rq=1), а также хорошие ответы здесь: [А существует ли инкапсуляция, если есть рефлексия?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454830/%D0%90-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Если сказать кратко: для соблюдения парадигмы ООП, инкапсуляции; для удобства и красоты кода; для сокрытия реализации от пользователя; для того, чтобы в наследуемых классах, или реализующих ваш интерфейс, можно было переопределить получение значения нужного поля, ну и так далее.

И, да: по сути, вы не получаете доступа к полю, вы получаете доступ к методу, который возвращает значение того или иного параметра. Также, метод не всегда может возвращать/устанавливать именно само значение поля. Как верно подмечено в ответах на один из перечисленных выше вопросов, благодаря инкапсуляции, те пользователи, которые будут использовать ваш класс, будут знать, какие поля можно читать, какие перезаписывать, а какие трогать вообще не стоит. Да и вам самим будет удобнее, тем более если будет необходимость вернуться к этому коду через длительное время.

Comment: Да ввиду отсутствия опыта, поначалу путаешься, разобрался (более менее) спасибо! всем добра)